# Attendee Status for an Event

Tags: eventbrite

I am trying to get the status of an `Attendee` from the `EventBrite API`, using the `event_get_attendee_list` method.  From the `Eventbrite UI`, you can see that an attended was checked in, etc - how can I get that from the API?

Answer (score 1):

Your event's ticket sales information should be available via the event_list_attendees API call: 
http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_list_attendees/

Each attendee should have an associated 'barcode' object, which will include a "status" attribute. Tickets that have already been scanned will appear with status=used, while tickets that have yet to be scanned with have their status set to "unused"